# Escape character inconsistency when leading integers

Tags: python, directory, path, operating-system, escaping

I am having issues trying to manipulate a directory path due to weird goings on in with the escape characters.

When I try to run the following code on my directory path some of the escape characters are not converted and instead are displayed as smiley faces??

```
path = "\\ad.company.com\data\projects\office\2022\222222-project\01-WIP\01-3D\01-Central\Facade Option Study\222222-3DR-ZZ-XX-M3-A-XXXXX - Option Study.rvt" 

newPath = path.replace(os.sep, '/')
print(newPath)
```

output =

```
/ad.company.com/data/projects/office2222-project☺-WIP☺-3D☺-Central/Facade Option Study222-3DR-ZZ-XX-M3-A-XXXXX - Option Study.rvt
```

This is further confirmed as when I try to split the string using `path.split("\")` it skips the escape characters that the `os.sep` method replaces with smileys.

The inconsistency in conversion also aligns with VS Code displaying those escape characters and a number of trailing characters in a slightly different colour to the rest of the regular string (snip visible at the link below. )

[VS Code snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpfNe.png)

Is there something I don't know about escape characters when leading in front of integers?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Please post the error message as text not an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a raw string. It interprets backslashes literally, not as escape characters:

```py
path = r"\\ad.company.com\data\projects\office\2022\222222-project\01-WIP\01-3D\01-Central\Facade Option Study\222222-3DR-ZZ-XX-M3-A-XXXXX - Option Study.rvt"
```

`'\2'` is not the same as `'\\2'` - it is actually the same as `chr(2)` (not an actual letter)

Read the documentation for raw strings [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).

Comment: Yes, your intuition served you well this time. Please update your question with what it means to python to have a `'\'` just before some digits in a string.

Comment: @TheThonnu ahhh thats the ticket. Thanks for that!